# Function to encrypt a string doesn't work

Tags: c++

i have created this function to encrypt a string , but it doesn't work .

The software searches each character of string "s" in the main, just find it (in strings z1 and z2) replaces it with the character in three positions more ahead

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string change(string& inp)
{

    string z1 = {"abcdefghilmnopqrtsvzabc"};
    string z2 = {"ABCDEFGHILMNOPQRSTUVZABC"};

    for(char c : inp)
    {
        if(z1.find(c) != string::npos) //string::npos is the "false" member 
        {
            auto x = z1.find(c);       //returned by **z1.find(c)**
            c = z1[x + 3];
            // The software searches each character, just find it (in strings z1 and z2) 
            // replaces it with the character in three positions more ahead
        }
        else
        {
            auto y = z2.find(c);
            c = z2[y + 3];
        }
    }
    return inp;
}

int main()
{
    string s = {"abcd"};

    cout << change(s) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Step through with a debugger.

Comment: I dont know how use it , i study C++ for 2 months and at the university the professor didnt tell us how to use it

Comment: @themagiciant95 Time to learn it then.

Comment: If you're using an IDE, it usually consists of clicking on the left side of a line to set a breakpoint and then choosing to use the debugger and hitting the button that says Step. I guarantee 5-10 minutes of looking would explain basic usage for whatever IDE it is. The command line is a bit more involved in general, but not too bad if you learn the couple of basic commands you'd need.

Comment: @themagiciant95 if you dont have access to a debugger, you can always `cout` information to help you debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get not a reference to the character in your string by your `for` loop, you get a variable `c` with the value of the character. Manipulating `c` does not change the given string `inp`. Change your loop back from c++11 style to:

```
for(int i=0;i<inp.length();i++ ){                       
    if(z1.find(inp[i])!=string::npos){       //string::npos is the "false" member 
        auto x =z1.find(inp[i]);             //returned by **z1.find(c)**
        inp[i]=z1[x+3];                      
                                         //The software searches each character, just find it (in strings z1 and z2) 
    }                                    //replaces it with the character in three positions more ahead
    else                                
    {
        auto y=z2.find(inp[i]);
        inp[i]=z2[y+3];
    }
}
```

PS: I tried to change the given code as less as possible. Not to give the best solution for the given problem or other possible bugs.

**UPDATE**

themagiciant95 (asking the question) got a better solution himself:

```
for(char &c:inp){
```

I missed that.

Comment: Thanks so much , it was a so stupid error :) . Just add a "&" to "for(char c:inp)" and now it works

Comment: @themagiciant95 not bad for only two month C++ anyway. Of course there is always room for improvement ;-)